# How to store filename created with fs.writeFile in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, filenames

I have this in my code:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${Date.now()}.pdf`)
```

How can I store this generated filename into a variable?

Comment: Uh, assign it to a variable first, then use the variable in the `writeFileSync` command?

Answer (score 1):

```
let filename = Date.now();
fs.writeFileSync(`${filename}.pdf`);
```

or

```
let filename = `${Date.now()}.pdf`;
fs.writeFileSync(filename);
```